# Snap.svg draggin Path Element

Tags: javascript, svg, snap.svg

I'm trying to drag a Path element with Snap.SVG, I'm using drag method

when method is called without parmeteres it seems to work ok, but when I add the listeners I cant make it work, It's looks like is not posible to change to position x,y attributes

```
start = () ->
    console.log("Stop move, ox=" + this.ox + ", oy=" + this.oy);


moveFunc =  (dx, dy, posx, posy) ->
    this.attr( { cx: posx , cy: posy } )


stop = () ->
    console.log("Stop move, ox=" + this.ox + ", oy=" + this.oy);

p.drag( moveFunc, start, stop)
```

The previos code doesnt work with path element, but it does with circle.

Next code can move it but when drag it again loose the last position

```
moveFunc =  (dx, dy, posx, posy) ->
        this.transform( "translate("+dx+", "+dy+")")
```

So guessing, last method do the trick for translate it, but it doesnt  really change the position.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To move a path, you will need to transform it, try this format.

```
this.transform('t' + dx + ',' + dy );
```

However, as mentioned it won't keep the last position. For that you need to store the transform on the mouse down....

```
var move = function(dx,dy) {
        this.attr({
                    transform: this.data('origTransform') + (this.data('origTransform') ? "T" : "t") + [dx, dy]
                });
}

var start = function() {
        this.data('origTransform', this.transform().local );
}
```

[example](http://svg.dabbles.info/snaptut-drag)

Comment: You are right, I've seen that example but didn't work for me. It turns out that was my mistake when using ternary operator with coffeescript. Regards